# MimeMessage change the sendData on existing Mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, message, mime-message

```
try (
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(source);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(target);
    ) {
        byte[] emlBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
        Message mimeMessage = createMimeMessage(emlBytes);

        String date = "Wed, 16 Oct 2013 11:25:07 +0200";
        mimeMessage.setHeader("Date", date);
        System.out.println(mimeMessage.getSentDate());
        output.write(emlBytes);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

}

I have to change the send date on existing email file. But after the execution the file have the same date as before. It doesnt get the new send date. I think it is because mimeMessage creates a new instance but doesnt change the emlBytes but I have to pass a emlBytes in output.write() I dont know how to pass the emlBytes which was customed by mimeMessage. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MimeMessage isn't going to change the original source of the data since it comes from an InputStream.  But you can use the `MimeMessage.writeTo` method to write the updated message to an OutputStream, e.g.,

```
mimeMessage.writeTo(output);
```